# How to call the Click event on a page in the Windows Forms WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How call Click event on button in WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HtmlElement.InvokeMember() method.  Here's an example that clicks the Google home page "I feel lucky" button:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
  if (webBrowser1.Url.Host.EndsWith("google.com")) {
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement ask = doc.All["q"];
    HtmlElement lucky = doc.All["btnI"];
    ask.InnerText = "stackoverflow";
    lucky.InvokeMember("click");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event gets invoked in response to a user clicking on the control.  You (normally) wouldn't 'call' the event directly yourself.

Can you clarify your question?

Comment: +1 true, poorly stated question, he really should have said something like "how would you interact with controls like buttons on a document in the WebBrowser control"